# How do I fix the tab rotation in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I use a Japanese keyboard and the universal way to change tabs in any application on Mac is `CMD + SHIFT + [ or ]` depending on the direction.

After Chrome's recent update, I noticed that this doesn't work anymore. I have to press the `CMD + SHIFT + @` key instead which is the `[` key in the USA keyboard.

It's really hurting my cadence since I have to rely on a different set of shortcuts to change between tabs on ONLY Chrome. Does anyone know how to fix this?

For your reference:
Japanese keyboard `@` sign is next to `p` and brackets next to that: https://www.kanpai-japan.com/sites/default/files/styles/og/public/uploads/2015/09/clavier-japonais.jpg

USA keyboard where the left bracket is next ot the `p`:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVGzR.jpg

Comment: Update: This has been fixed

Answer (score 0):

(*I'm not a Mac person and would be happy if some real Mac person will help here.*)

You should consider remapping your keyboard so that the key-combinations that you are
used to get translated to the new key combinations.

The product that is usually recommended to use in such cases is the free
[Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/blob/master/README.md) :

> Karabiner-Elements is a powerful utility for keyboard customization on macOS Sierra or later.

You may find the Manual [here](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html),
where your case is probably that of "Complex Modifications", defined as
"Map keys by complex rules. e.g., key to modifiers, modifiers+key to key, send key event if pressed alone, etc.".